# c# List Enums return values

Tags: c#, enums

```
public enum Colors
{
    red,
    blue,
    green,
    yellow
}
```

I want to use it switch case

```
public void ColorInfo(string colorName)
{
    Colors tryParseResult;

    if (Enum.TryParse<Colors>(colorName, out tryParseResult))
    {
        // the string value could be parsed into a valid Colors  value
        switch (tryParseResult)
        {
            // I need a checking like (colorname=="red")
            case Colors.red:
                question = question.Where(at => at.Color == tryParseResult);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

This works when in string I have one value "red" or "blue". But in string I can also have "red,blue" or "yellow,green". Any suggestion on how to build a linq method which will return a values which have color is red, blue etc?

Comment: You can use the [.Split()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=net-7.0) function to separate the strings on the ',' character.

Comment: "red,blue" isn't a "colorName", it's the name of _multiple_ colors. Consider changing the parameter name to be more clear or do input validation head of time.

Comment: Sounds like you want a [Flags](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.flagsattribute?view=net-7.0) enum. Parsing that like shown here will then result in a combination of the enum values. A check like `tryParseResult.HasFlag(Colors.red)` will then be needed to find out if the color is contained in the result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your input string is reliable you can handle this using [enum Flags](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.flagsattribute?view=net-7.0):

```
void Main()
{
    // pass true to ignore case
    var tryParseResult = Enum.TryParse<Colors>("red, blue,yellow", true, out var values);

    if (tryParseResult) {
        Console.WriteLine(values);
    }
    
    if (values.HasFlag(Colors.red)) {
        Console.WriteLine("Red was specified");
    }
    else {
        Console.WriteLine("Red was not specified");
    }

    if (values.HasFlag(Colors.green))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Green was specified");
    }
    else {
        Console.WriteLine("Green was not specified");
    }
}

[Flags]
public enum Colors
{
    none = 0,
    red = 1,
    blue = 2,
    green = 4,
    yellow = 8
}
```

Output:

> red, blue, yellow
> Red was specified
> Green was not specified